# Enforce loading of php.ini files from current folder

Tags: php, configuration, php.ini

My goal is to increase the maximum file size for uploads in WordPress. I have followed the steps on [this SE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/how-to-increase-the-file-size-limit-for-media-uploads) and [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/) (except the .htaccess part, because it's runnning nginx and AFAIK nginx ignores .htaccess files), to no avail. Looks like it is ignoring `php.ini` files from the current folder.

On an unrelated WP install I run on a shared host I rent, if I place a `php.ini` file on the WordPress folder (or any folder), the parameters on that file will take precedence over the original `php.ini` folder, and the unspecified parameters will be inherited.

I assume this is default PHP behaviour. The beginning of `/etc/php.ini` seems to corroborate that:

```
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.

; PHP attempts to find and load this configuration from a number of locations.
; The following is a summary of its search order:
; 1. SAPI module specific location.
; 2. The PHPRC environment variable. (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 3. A number of predefined registry keys on Windows (As of PHP 5.2.0)
```

> **; 4. Current working directory (except CLI)**

```
; 5. The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP
; (otherwise in Windows)
; 6. The directory from the --with-config-file-path compile time option, or the
; Windows directory (C:\windows or C:\winnt)
; See the PHP docs for more specific information.
; http://php.net/configuration.file
```

The [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) also seems to agree:

> In addition to the main php.ini file, **PHP scans for INI files in each directory**, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and working its way up to the current document root (as set in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']). In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned.

In my instance, looks like it is not working; adding a `php.ini` or `php5.ini` file with `upload_max_filesize`, etc, won't have the desired effect. Adding `@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );` to the end of WP's `functions.php` file, as advised elsewhere, won't work as well.

Output of `php --ini`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/posix.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

From `phpinfo()`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php.d/curl.ini, /etc/php.d/dom.ini, /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini, /etc/php.d/json.ini, /etc/php.d/mbstring.ini, /etc/php.d/mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php.d/phar.ini, /etc/php.d/posix.ini, /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini, /etc/php.d/sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php.d/sysvsem.ini, /etc/php.d/sysvshm.ini, /etc/php.d/wddx.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini, /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php.d/xsl.ini, /etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

- OS: CentOS release 6.5 (Final) 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64
- PHP version: 5.4.30
- Web Server: nginx-1.6.0-2.el6.ngx.x86_64

Comment: Paste bin your `/etc/php.ini` and the contents of your `nginx.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

*With out seeing your config files, I can only assume..*

Make sure that you have made the following changes to your `nginx.conf` file:

> http {
>
> ```
> client_max_body_size $New_File_Size;
> ```
>
> }

Replace `$New_File_Size` to what you set your php.ini max file size to.

Once you have added this line to your existing nginx.conf file, you need to restart your services.

`service php-fpm restart`

`service nginx reload`

If this doesn't work, paste bin your config files and I will help you further.

You should also update your PHP version.